# Codename One Activate GPS

Tags: gps, codenameone

I work on an app for IOS and WPhone. I need to activate the GPS before start an activity or new screen

On Android I use this:

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                    Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(myIntent);
```

Which is the proper manner to do it on CN1 both for IOS and WPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to take a look on **LocationManager** on CodenameOne. It provides all the tools to manage such things as GPS (Maybe `LocationManager.isGPSEnabled()` ?).
By the way, **you have to set build hints** in codename one to authorize your app to access GPS.

Comment: For GPS to work on iOS you must define the `ios.locationUsageDescription` build hint as explained here http://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_sending_arguments_to_the_build_server